# What functon to use to find area under the curve?

Tags: r, area

I have plotted ecdf curve in R and now I want to find the area under that curve. So how can I do that or what function can I use  to do that.

[image]

I dont know which function to use so have not tried anything.

Comment: That’s not a CDF: the area under the curve is clearly greater than one.

Comment: @Limey Looks like a proper CDF to me: approaches zero for $x\to\-\infty$ and one for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @cdalitz.  You're right.  Brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the area under a curve you can simply numerically integrate it. There is the builtin function `integrate` in R for doing so:

```
> F <- ecdf(iris$Sepal.Length)
> integrate(F, 5,7)
1.149332 with absolute error < 7.5e-05
```

I have no idea, however, why you want to compute the area under a CDF (cumulative distribution function): As the CDF approaches one for $x\to\infty$, the area under the CDF becomes large beyond any bound as the upper integral limit increases.